# How to fetch supervisor name

Tags: oracle

I have to solve a question

I have two tables such as employees and supervisors

```
Employees table
------------------------             
firstname    
lastname    
employeeid


Supervisors table
---------------             
supervisor(employeeid)    
employeeid (employeeid)    
and other columns,
```

Puzzle:

From this i have to fetch the Supervisors name from the employees table by fetching the supervisor from the Supervisors table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM Employees 
WHERE Employeeid IN (
  SELECT Distinct supervisor FROM Supervisors
)
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.FirstName, a.LastName
FROM Employees a
INNER JOIN Supervisors b ON a.EmployeeID = b.supervisor
```

UPDATED :

```
SELECT b.FirstName, b.LastName, c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM Supervisors a
LEFT JOIN Employees b ON a.EmployeeID = b.supervisor
LEFT JOIN Employees c ON a.EmployeeID = c.employeeid
```

Comment: I neeed employeename along with the supervisor name

Comment: from your question you only want supervisorname. but anyway I updated my answer